# VB.net TCPListner works once, then acts strange

Tags: vb.net, tcplistener

I am working on writing a TCP listener to accept printer output for a project.  I have written the following code, and it works great, once. After the first print job is processed, it acts strange.

At runtime the program sits at the line tcpClient = TheTCPListener.AcceptTcpClient() until something connects, then it processes the data being sent.  The first print job works great. If I send 5 more print jobs, they may all go through, or they may sit on the tcpClient = TheTCPListener.AcceptTcpClient() line for a while, then keep processing the code without getting any data, and loop back to that spot again.  After the first time, it and may or may not actually get any data, but will keep looping as long as there is something in the print queue waiting to send.  Eventually, it will process all of the print jobs, but I can't figure out why it works perfectly once (EVERY TIME) then may or may not work correctly the next time data is sent.

Any help or suggestions are VERY appreciated!

```
    Public Sub EnableListener()
    Dim TheTCPListener As New TcpListener(IPAdr, PortNumber)
    Dim tcpClient As TcpClient = Nothing
    Dim networkStream As NetworkStream = Nothing
    Dim UseThisFileName As String = ""
    Dim bytestoread As Integer = 0
    Dim temploopcount As Integer = 0

    'start the TCP listener
    TheTCPListener.Start()

    While (True)
       'Reset The Size of the byte chunk
        bytestoread = 0

        'Wait for connection
        tcpClient = TheTCPListener.AcceptTcpClient()

        'Set the buffer size large enough to handle the whole file
        tcpClient.ReceiveBufferSize = 60000000

        'set the filename to write too
        UseThisFileName = getfilenameext()

        networkStream = tcpClient.GetStream

        'verify that the stream has data to read 
        While networkStream.DataAvailable

            networkStream.Read(bytes, 0, 60000000)
            bytestoread = 0

        ' Get the size of the bytes with data
            For x = 0 To 59999999
                If bytes(x) <> Nothing Then
                    bytestoread = bytestoread + 1

                End If
            Next

           'calls the sub to append to the file 
           writebtyestofile(PrintFolder + UseThisFileName, bytestoread)

           'resets the bytes array to empty 
           For x = 0 To 59999999 bytes(x) = Nothing Next

        End While

        'Close TcpClient.  Without this, the print job never finishes sending in the print queue
        tcpClient.Close()
    End While 'this loops the listener forever, unless the program is shut down.
End Sub
```

Comment: Create a client yourself and run both at the same time and see how your server works. If it works fine with your client then there is something about the other client that is causing the unexpected behaviour, so you need to find out what that is.

Comment: Thanks @jmcilhinney.  Interestingly, writing a TCPclient app to send the .ps file resulting in nothing sending (it doesn't queue like a print spool).  I did get it resolved though.  I added a brief wait before checking for networkStream.DataAvailable and that fixed both sending from the test client and the print spool.  Thank you for the suggestion.